# How to get SubCollection's Document Id in Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Datalike this:

```
Collection
         -document
              - subCollection 
                         - randomDocumentId
                                           -subSubCollection
```

EDITED:

**and randomDocmentId have a collection** so I want to that collection that are stored in my randomDocumentId;

How can I access that particular randomDocumentID

Comment: You want all the documents of a subclass? Right

Comment: not only particular document

Comment: that matches the string word like `userName`

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Try it*

```
 public void getDocuments(String documentsId){
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference document = firebaseFirestore.collection("COLLECTION_NAME")
            .document("Documnets_id").collection("SUB_COLLECTION").document(documentsId);
    
    document.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener< DocumentSnapshot >() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                String result = documentSnapshot.getString("FIELD_NAME"); // Which you want
                Log.d(TAG, result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

*Call The method*

```
        getDocuments("Your documents id");
```

Comment: Yes you are right but but ! what if I have 100 of documents then can I have to write it manually.

Comment: Simple call the method and replace with documentId